# Set focus to the next input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap form where I want to set the focus to the next 'enabled' input element upon pressing enter key. When I press enter in Barcode input element, I want to set the focus to the Quantity input element since it is the next enabled input element.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-3 pr-0">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtBarcode">Barcode</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtBarcode" name="barcode" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-7 pl-2 pr-0">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtPartDesc">Description</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtPartDesc" name="part_desc" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2 pl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtUom">UoM</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtUom" name="barcode" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-4 pr-0">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtQuantity">Quantity</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtQuantity" name="barcode" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
$(":input").keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $(this).nextAll(':input:enabled').first().focus();
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: `.nextAll` only looks at siblings, not the whole HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next()`, `nextAll()`, and the other similar methods are for finding siblings. Since none of your inputs are actual siblings this will not work.

What you can do however is:

1. Get a jQuery object of all the enabled inputs

   ```
   var enabledInputs = $("input:enabled");
   ```
2. Get the index of the current input in that jQuery object using [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

   ```
   var idx = enabledInputs.index(this);
   ```
3. Then using that index get the element at index+1 using [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

   ```
   enabledInputs.eq(idx+1).focus();
   ```

---

Demo

```js
$(":input").keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      var enabledInputs = $("input:enabled");
      var idx = enabledInputs.index(this);
      enabledInputs.eq(idx+1).focus()
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-3 pr-0">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtBarcode">Barcode</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtBarcode" name="barcode" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-7 pl-2 pr-0">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtPartDesc">Description</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtPartDesc" name="part_desc" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2 pl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtUom">UoM</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtUom" name="barcode" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-4 pr-0">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtQuantity">Quantity</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtQuantity" name="barcode" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I was amazed by the prompt response I got. Thank you a lot... It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The next input is not a sibling of the `#barcode` input, so `nextAll` won't work at that point. Try navigating to the parent's parent, the `div class="col-`, and *then* use `nextAll` to recursively search through that parent's siblings until a matching element is found:

```js
$(":input").keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode !== 13) return;
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .parent() // get to the `class=col-#` element
    .nextAll(':input:enabled')
    .first()
    .focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 pr-0">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtBarcode">Barcode</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtBarcode" name="barcode" class="form-control form-control-sm">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-7 pl-2 pr-0">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtPartDesc">Description</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtPartDesc" name="part_desc" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 pl-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtUom">UoM</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtUom" name="barcode" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 pr-0">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtQuantity">Quantity</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtQuantity" name="barcode" class="form-control form-control-sm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. @Patrick's answer worked 'Out of the box' . Anyway I am studying your input as well since I am new to js world (Y)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then one solution to this problem is to update your `keydown()` handler like so:

```
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {

      // Get all enabled inputs in the document
      var inputs = $('input:enabled');

      // Iterate all inputs, searching for the index of the "next" input to "this"
      for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        // If the "global" index of "this" input is found
        if( $(inputs).eq(i).is( $(this) ) ) {

          // Then select the "next" input by incrementing the index, and call
          // focus on that input if it exists
          inputs.eq(i + 1)
          .css({ border : '1px solid red' }) // Added to help visualise focus, remove this line 
          .focus();

          // Exit the loop now that focus has been called on "next" input
          break
        }
      } 
    }
```

The idea here is to select the next input element based on the order that they occur in the DOM, rather than to select the next input element based on adjacent siblings to the input that "enter" is pressed. This solution also corrects a few minor errors in your code's selector syntax. Here's a working demo:

```js
$("input").keydown(function(event){
 
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
     
      var inputs = $('input:enabled');
      
      for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if( $(inputs).eq(i).is( $(this) ) ) {
          inputs.eq(i + 1)
          .css({ border : '1px solid red' }) // Added to help visualise focus, remove this line 
          .focus()
          break
        }
      } 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-3 pr-0">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtBarcode">Barcode</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtBarcode" name="barcode" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-7 pl-2 pr-0">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtPartDesc">Description</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtPartDesc" name="part_desc" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2 pl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtUom">UoM</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtUom" name="barcode" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-4 pr-0">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtQuantity">Quantity</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtQuantity" name="barcode" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. @Patrick's answer worked 'Out of the box' . Anyway I am studying your input as well since I am new to js world (Y)

Comment: @LakmalPremaratne hey you're welcome! Hope this is of some help to you in your learning :-)